# Why is my enemy behind my background / tilemap? Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I just can't understand why is my enemy behind the background / tilemap. I checked the layering, because I've had the same problem with the player. Any idea how to fix it?

This is the level load function

```
function stage1() {
  Game.add.image(0, 0, 'background');

  map1 = Game.add.tilemap('level1');

  map1.addTilesetImage('32x32_tileset_mario', 'tileset');

  map1.setCollisionByExclusion([]);

  ground = map1.createLayer(0);

  // layer1 = map1.createLayer(1)

  // map1.setTileIndexCallback(392, pK1);

  enemyCreate();

  player = Game.add.sprite(200, 800, 'player');
  player.anchor.setTo(0.5);
  player.scale.setTo(0.4);
  player.animations.add('fly', [0, 1, 2], 10, true);

  Game.physics.enable(player);
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  player.body.gravity.y = 600;

  console.log('stage 1');
}
```

and this is the function to create the enemies.

```
function enemyCreate() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    NPC.create(x + 1300, 1940, 'player');
    x += 200;

    NPC.scale.setTo(0.4);

    // NPC.body.immovable = true
  }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Here's the full code - https://pastebin.com/ZM2Sg2Aa